# How to convert from QObject* to QGenericArgument for recursive QMetaObject::newInstance(...)

Tags: c++, qt, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

### I'm on DI IoC Developing with Qt MetaObject System.

```
class Resolver
{
public:
  template <typename BaseType, typename DerivedType>
  void Bind() { ... }

  template <typename T>
  T* Resolve() { ... }
  ...

private:
  QObject* ResolveByName(QString typeName) { ... }
  QHash<QString, QMetaObject> _container;
  ...
}
```

Bind method store information about types in `_container`, and `Resolve` method use this information to create instance.
I'm using `QMetaObject::newInstance(QGenericArgumet arg1, QGenericArgumet arg2, ...)` and recursive constructor arguments resolving.
For example we have such classes:

```
class IUserService { ... }

class NativeUserService : public IUserService
{
  NativeUserService(IUserRepository* userRepository) { ... }
}
```

---

After client call this:

```
IUserService* userService = resolver.Resolve<IUserService>();

Resolver calls ResolveByName("IUserService*"):

QObject* ResolveByName(Qstring typeName)
{
  QMetaObject meta = _container.value(typeName);
  ...
  for (quint8 index = 0; index < 10; index++)
  {
    ...
    QString argType = constructorType.parameterTypes().at(index);
    QObject *argValue = ResolveByName(argType);
    ctorArgs << QGenericArgument(???);
  }
  ...
  return meta.newInstance(ctorArgs[0], ctorArgs[1], ...);
}
```

**The problem:**
How to pass `meta.newInstance()` Result to `meta.newInstance()` Argument (convert from `QObject*` to `QGenericArgument`)?

Comment: QGenericArgument(argName, static_cast<void*>(argValue)) don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problems. The key is to use `static_cast<const void *>(&argValue)`. More details you can find here [QtDependencyResolver](https://github.com/SPupko/QtDependencyResolver).

Answer (score 3):

You should not use QGenericArgument directly. There is `Q_ARG` for that.

```
Q_ARG(QObject*, object)
```

Comment: Yes @Riateche, but i need dynamic arg types. For example:  `Q_ARG(IUserRepository*, userRepository)`. And i don't now how to make this cast `QObject *argValue = ResolveByName(argType); IUserRepository* userRepository = qobject_cast<IUserRepository*>(argValue );` in dynamic.